# DocuSign: place signature at location of arbitrary text string e.g. {{SIGNATURE GOES HERE}}

Tags: docusignapi

I am going to be using DocuSign on a project, and have never worked with it before. I saw an example here where the signature is placed at an arbitrary pixel coordinate location on a PDF, but is there a way to tell DocuSign to find an arbitrary text string in a PDF and to replace that string with a signature request?

For example:  `{{SIGNATURE GOES HERE}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the "anchoring tabs" feature of DocuSign to accomplish this. The documentation includes details on how to achieve this.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm?Highlight=anchor

NOTE: DocuSign will not remove the placeholder text. If you do not want the text to appear, we recommend making the text color match the document background color (i.e: white text on a white page/document).

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify what this means? "You cannot use the same anchored tab for different recipients for the same document."

Comment: I believe it is just re-stating the fact that any tab must be assigned/owned by a single recipient. There is a concept of 'allowing all recipients to edit a tab', however at the end of the day every day is still owned/assigned to a single recipient.